# Website files loading slow HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website has the spinning wheel of death for about 10 seconds and then fully loads my entire website. Would the cause of this be the CSS? HTML? JS?

I'm assuming it would have to do with the javascript as images don't load until the entire website does.

I haven't uploaded the site files yet, but I'm just wondering what a possibility would be for this, as if this is common and the common solution would be to remove as much JS as possible, or limit CSS, etc.

Comment: You might want to run a page speed test and start from there, this way you can ask for specific problems, try: http://nibbler.silktide.com/ or https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: It's hard to say without a link to your site or code samples. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you think you're file sizes are the problem, you could try compressing them with Gzip for transmitting them to the client. You can add the following to your .htaccess file to enable Gzip compression:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Outside of that, we would need more detail on what your web server configurations are.

Comment: this would reduce the size completely and I wouldn't need to do anything else?

Comment: This will compress the files your are sending to your client and then decompress them once they are received. This will help with the data transmission time, so it should help with reducing the load time. Unfortunately, I don't currently have access to my own website to test this change out for you.